# What's the equivalent of C++ `const` return types in Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi

I have the following C++ code:

header: (inside the class)

```
virtual const bigint &getPopulation() ;
```

implementation:

```
static bigint negone = -1 ;
const bigint &hlifealgo::getPopulation() {
   // note:  if called during gc, then we cannot call calcPopulation
   // since that will mess up the gc.
   if (!popValid) {
      if (inGC) {
        needPop = 1 ;
        return negone ;
      } else {
        calcPopulation(root) ;
        popValid = 1 ;
        needPop = 0 ;
      }
   }
   return population ;
}
```

I ported it to Delphi and it works just fine. 
Still I'm a bit puzzled about the const return type.

Can I just ignore the `const` in translation, or is there something to watch out for here?

Is there an analog in Delphi of this concept?

Comment: I'm assuming the BigInt gets passed by reference (because it's 32bit code and passing a 64bit value by reference is faster) and the const prevents it from being altered.

Comment: the type is `const bigint&` so yes it is a reference

Comment: In which case the equivalent would be: `procedure getP(var population: int64);` except that the `var` reference is a `const` _(if that makes sense)_

Comment: That's not really equivalent, Johan. In C++, the caller could store the result in a const-reference variable. Any further modifications to the `population` variable that got returned by that function could be observed in that *other* const-reference variable, too. To mimic that behavior, you'd instead need `function getP: PInt64` with the promise that the caller won't use that pointer to modify the pointed-to data. The bottom line is that Delphi has no notion of const as part of a *type*.

Comment: @RobKennedy, ok I get it now, the `&` makes the function return a pointer (pass by reference), because it's really a pointer the `const` is needed to prevent you from missing with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no analogue to this in Delphi. What you have here is a `const` reference. In Delphi there is no mechanism to distinguish between mutable references and constant references. All references can be used to mutate an object. So this is not particularly an issue related to the `const` return type, more that Delphi does not support constant references.

You have no choice but to ignore `const` references when porting code from C++ to Delphi. You cannot distinguish between different types of references in Delphi, there is only one.